# How to get cpu utilization data for phantomJS browser?

Tags: c#, phantomjs, nunit

```
public static readonly PerformanceCounter theCPUCounter =
        new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

    public static readonly PerformanceCounter theMemCounter =
        new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");

    public  static readonly PerformanceCounter theCPUCounterPhantomJS =
        new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", Process.GetProcessesByName("phantomjs").ToString());  

    public static void getCurrentCpuUsage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(theCPUCounter.NextValue() + " %");
    }

    public static void getAvailableRAM()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(theMemCounter.NextValue() + " MB");           
    }

    public static void getCurrentCpuUsagePhantomJS()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(theCPUCounterPhantomJS.NextValue() + " %");
    }
```

I want cpu utilization data for PhantomJS browser. Here is the code that I am using. I just want to know that what parameter I can enter instead of  **Process.GetProcessesByName("phantomjs").ToString()**. I tried many approach but it fails and gave me exception **System.InvalidOperationException : Instance 'System.Diagnostics.Process[]' does not exist in the specified Category.** .The name of the process is **phantomjs.exe**[image] that shows in task manager. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx7e9t8e(v=vs.110).aspx) - this is how you should instantiate the performance counter in your case:

```
new PerformanceCounter(
    "Process", 
    "% Processor Time", 
    "phantomjs");
```

Process.GetProcessesByName returns an array of processes, and so the ToString results in "System.Diagnostics.Process[]", which is not a valid instance name, not under the Processor category, and not under the Process category.